# angular ng-disable not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, button, disabled-control

I'm trying to disable a button from a controller when a directive emits a ready status.

I'm passing in a boolean to `ng-disabled`:

```
<button ng-disabled="{{pointsClaimed}}" ng-click="playVideo()">{{buttonText}}</button>
```

My controller:

```
    $scope.buttonText = 'Watch Video to Claim Points';
    $scope.pointsClaimed = false;

    $scope.$on('pointsClaimed', function(){
        $scope.buttonText = 'Points Claimed!';
        $scope.pointsClaimed = true;
    });
```

I can see that the button is changing from false to true:

[image]

[image]

But the actual button isn't being disabled.

If I hardcode in true or false, it works as expected. If the value is changing as expected in the HTML, why isn't the button being disabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think you need the curly brackets. Try..

```
<button ng-disabled="pointsClaimed" ng-click="playVideo()">{{buttonText}}</button>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/NEZBI5dcCnMfpGSehoKX)

Also a good demo in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled).